# How can you check if the input is int or float (not string,list etc.) without using try or except?

Tags: python, compiler-errors

I was given a task of making an unbreakable quadratic equation in Python.

```
ax**2 + bx + c = 0
```

I cannot use any imported libraries or functions and cannot use `try and except`

I need to input the values of a, b and c manually.

The problem is I just have no idea how to check if string is int or float without catching an error.

I found the isdigit() function but it won't work on float and other questions like this use imports or try: except: functions. Also, I imagine, negative numbers can be used too.

Is that really possible?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your actual, full and complete assignment or exercise? Please [edit] your question to include it. Including any limitations and requirements,

Comment: As for the `isdigit` function, it can be used on any decimal number, even floating point numbers. You just have to add an extra check for the decimal point (or comma, it can be different in different locales). If there's a decimal point then it's a floating point number, otherwise it's an integer.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude This would also need a check for leading unary plus or minus in the first character (+3, -5 would be valid integers) and maybe even scientific notations of floats (how about -1.5e23) and then it becomes a bit messy.

Comment: @simon I didn't say it would be easy. I wouldn't even say it would be a "bit messy", but rather *very* messy. :-)  But it all comes back to the unknown assignment of the OP, and the reasons for the seemingly arbitrary limitations.

Comment: Why would you want to reinvent the wheel? Writing pure Python code to determine if a string represents a floating point number might be an interesting academic challenge but when there are already tools in the standard toolbox, use them

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude fully agreed :)